# Session not maintained between httpUrlConn calls

Tags: java, android, session, httpurlconnection

I have the following method:

```
  public static String postJSONObject(String myurl, JSONObject parameters, Context ctx) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            StringBuffer response = null;
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(parameters.toString());
            Log.d("Parameters to string", "params.tostring" + parameters.toString());
            writer.close();
            out.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("responseCode" + responseCode);

            switch (responseCode) {
                case 200:

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    response = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();

                    List cookieList = conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
                    if (cookieList != null) {
                        for (Object cookieTemp : cookieList) {
                            CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(conn.getURL().toString(), cookieTemp.toString());
                        }
                    }
                    String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(new URL("https://exaperth.exacrm.com").getHost());
                    System.out.println("Cookie after adding " + cookie);
                    return response.toString();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I post username and Password to the server and the server creates a session, the "Set-Cookie" is saved into CookieManager like:

```
PHPSESSID=a3d2367f8a5a3221e9bad1a91a34fd55; ci_session=a%3A4%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%221381c152699fb61d04663c9b854ecdd7%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A14%3A%22182.59.245.196%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A60%3A%22Dalvik%2F2.1.0+%28Linux%3B+U%3B+Android+5.1.1%3B+Nexus+5+Build%2FLMY48B%29%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1447140920%3B%7Ddd2c014724b9ca061b50774f1fea235d
```

in the second method below:

```
public static String doHttpUrlConnectionAction(String desiredUrl, String cookieValue) throws Exception {
        URL url = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder;
        try {

            url = new URL(desiredUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // just want to do an HTTP GET here
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            //  connection.setDoOutput(true);
            // give it 15 seconds to respond
            String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(new URL("https://exaperth.exacrm.com").getHost());
            System.out.println("Cookie from cookie store: " + cookie);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
            connection.setReadTimeout(15 * 1000);
            connection.connect();


            // read the output from the server
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            // close the reader; this can throw an exception too, so
            // wrap it in another try/catch block.
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I use the same cookie, but somehow, the session is not valid, I get the login page. What am I missing?